# Create column in R that increments every row to length of dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, seq

I would like to add a column to my dataframe that starts at 0 and increments 0.002 every row till the end of the dataframe.

I tried:

```
NewCol <- seq(0,len(DF),0.002))
DF <- cbind(DF, NewCol)
```

My desired output would be:
0.00
0.002
0.004
0.006
...to the end of the dataframe

The NewCol length was too long to cbind to my dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `nrow` for this inside the `seq` function like so

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:5), b = 6:10)
  a b
1 1 o
2 2 c
3 3 p
4 4 u
5 5 d

df$num = seq(0, by = 0.002, to = nrow(df)*0.002 - 0.002)

# simplified by @Ritchie Sacramento to

df$num = seq(0, by = 0.002, length.out = nrow(df))

  a b   num
1 1 o 0.000
2 2 c 0.002
3 3 p 0.004
4 4 u 0.006
5 5 d 0.008
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Can you explain why you do "(df)*0.002 - 0.002)?

Comment: @mpvalenc `seq(0, to = 1, by = 0.2)` will return a vector of length 6 as it includes both 0 and 1. R throws an error when we add it to the data.frame (you can try `df$test = 1:6`). So we simply ask it to return 1 less step in the sequence.  However, as pointed out by @RitchieSacramento, the `length.out` argument exists which does that for us.